# Where can I find the bitcoind bundled with bitcoin-qt in Ubuntu?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, ubuntu

I read that bitcoind comes bundled with bitcoin-qt, but I can't find it anywhere on my system after installing bitcoin-qt. I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If you start `bitcoin-qt` with the `-server` option, it also runs an RPC server, making it functionally equivalent to `bitcoind`.

Answer (score 0):

They are two different things. If you want to install bitcoind you will need to install it

```
apt-get install bitcoind
```

But you can't run both at the same time, since bitcoin-qt is the same as bitcoind but with a nice interface while bitcoind is just the daemon.